# Sum elements in python list

Tags: python, list, sum, element

Ho to sum this value in this list:

```
[{'name': 'Radio HF', **'quantidade': '1'**}, {'name': 'Radio HF', **'quantidade': '1'**}, {'name': 'chave fenda', 'quantidade': '2'}, {'name': 'Coletes salva-vidas', 'quantidade': '3'}]
```

example: if the [index] have same name I want to sum the value in `"quantidade"`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the reason but the type of your `'quantidade'` is `string`, so you have to cast it to `int` before doing the `sum`.

**Code**:

```
mylist = [{'name': 'Radio HF', 'quantidade': '1'}, 
           {'name': 'Radio HF', 'quantidade': '1'}, 
           {'name': 'chave fenda', 'quantidade': '2'}, 
           {'name': 'Coletes salva-vidas', 'quantidade': '3'}]

sums = {}

for x in mylist:
    sums[x['name']] = sums.get(x['name'],0) + int(x['quantidade'])
```

**Output**:

```
{'Radio HF': 2, 'chave fenda': 2, 'Coletes salva-vidas': 3}
```

Comment: thank you very much, that's what I was looking for. It worked perfect

Comment: Nice copy paste from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the dictionaries in the list and use a dictionary to sum the `quantidade` value by similar `name`.

```
lst = [{'name': 'Radio HF', 'quantidade': '1'},
       {'name': 'Radio HF', 'quantidade': '1'},
       {'name': 'chave fenda', 'quantidade': '2'},
       {'name': 'Coletes salva-vidas', 'quantidade': '3'}]

sums = {}
for d in lst:
    sums[d['name']] = sums.get(d['name'], 0) + int(d['quantidade'])

print(sums) # {'Radio HF': 2, 'chave fenda': 2, 'Coletes salva-vidas': 3}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn’t realise I posted the same solution as you. I modified my original code when I realised the OP wanted to add values for the same name and I had the code opened in Jupyter, I didn’t see your answer in advance. I’m upping your answer so we are even. Sorry